# React Button click lagging behind one click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read many answers to this question but can't get a solution to work for me.

This is a simple number pad component
when I click my number my state updates, but I can't get it to display the updated information until the second button click (which on the second button click the display variable only shows the info from the first button click and not both)
I am very new to react and I know that the state will batch and won't always update right away, but I just can't seem to make a work around that works. below is my full code (minus the css) to render my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class LoginPad extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            output:'',
            display:'',
        }
    }

    handleClick(n){
        if (n<=9){
            this.setState({output:this.state.output+n}, this.handlePW());
        }else if(n===12){
            this.setState({output:this.state.output.slice(0,-1)}, this.handlePW());
        }else{
            console.log("doing log in stuff");
        }
    }
    handlePW(){
        if(this.props.isPassword){
            const x=new Array(this.state.output.length + 1).join("*");
            this.setState({display: x});       
        }else{
            this.setState({display: this.state.output})
        }
        console.log(this.state.output)
        
        }

    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-sm-3 offset-sm-4'>
                <div className="dstroke">&nbsp;{this.state.display}</div>
                <div className='row'>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>1</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>2</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>3</div></button>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>4</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(5)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>5</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(6)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>6</div></button>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(7)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>7</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(8)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>8</div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(9)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>9</div></button>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                <button className="oBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(12)}><div className='col-sm-1  b'><i className="fas fa-backspace"></i></div></button>
                <button className="numBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(0)}><div className='col-sm-1 '>0</div></button>
                <button className="oBut"onClick={()=>this.handleClick(13)}><div className='col-sm-1 i'><i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></div></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
LoginPad.propTypes = {
    isPassword: PropTypes.bool
  };
  
LoginPad.defaultProps = {
    isPassword: false
  };
```

Comment: state is updated asynchronously. To see the updated state, component has to re-render. You can use `render()` method or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to log the updated state. Or pass a second optional argument to `this.setState` which is a callback function which is called after the state update.

Comment: this.forceUpdate() did not work .. i am using a call back function from setState to continue on with my processing of the varibles.. unsure how to use that to update the display string..

Comment: You called a function inside a callback  that is not what you intend to do, in `this.setState` 2nd argument needs to be the reference to the function and not a function call.

Comment: Inside the `handleClick` method, you are passing the result of calling `this.handlePW()` method to `this.setState`. This will call the `this.handlePW` immediately instead of calling it later after the state update. Change it from `this.handlePW()` to just `this.handlePW`

Comment: @badProgrammer - continuing from @Yousaf's comment above - the reason you are seeing the desirable in the second click is that on the first click the called function's (`this.handlePW`) changes are not batched as intended. In order, first the `this.handlePW` is executed then the result is passed to the `this.setState` as a second argument. So, in effect, during the first click, `this.handlePW` is called first and then `this.setState` where it is passed as `this.handlePW()` - therefore the `display` calculation is done before updating the `output` variable on first click - results in lag.